# Match first element of a tilde separated values string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to match the first element of this example string in Oracle SQL. Every element could contain every character or number except the tilde.

```
~a,c~d2f~@hi~~~j(l~e~~~~~~~~
```

The Result should be "a,c".

I really don't know how to achieve this.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this as well

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('~a,c~d2f~@hi~~~j(l~e~~~~~~~~', '[^~]+')  FROM dual;
```

This will search for the first non tilde set of characters and print it.

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: @EvertonAgner I have explained the logic in the post, from you question I realized that last two parameter was not required in the function. Thanks

Comment: I chose this answer as accepted answer because it contains only my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  trim (both '~' from REGEXP_SUBSTR('~a,c~d2f~@hi~~~j(l~e~~~~~~~~', '~[^~]+~') )
```

I have modified an example from the [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) and it fits to your one.